# Why is the Area2D sprite overlapping the ground in my Godot game and how do I resolve it?

Tags: collision, godot, godot4

Recently I installed godot and decided to make a game but there was a problem:
I added Area2d for character for collision detection but the area2d sprite is kind of sick because it is overlapping the ground see:

[See it is over lapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZXxo.png)
Please solve

Please solve it is very important

For @TheJalfireKnight

[Here You Go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEdL5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a suggestion: I am assuming you are using a physics body for the character (CharacterBody, StaticBody, ect.). If you just want collisions so it can't pass through the ground, just add a collision shape as the child of your character. Like this:

```
Player
|
--Sprite2D
|
--CollisionShape2D
```

Also it would be helpful to send a screenshot of your scene in the editor. Maybe the shape is wrong?

EDIT: I'm sorry for the late response. The reason is having custom collision detection like that isn't reliable. I would make the player a CharacterBody3D/KinematicBody3D, and put a collision shape as a parent of that. It will automatically do collision.

Comment: See the question I added the image of editor

Comment: I'm sorry I have been travelling and forgot to respond. Here I am, 2 months late. Here's an answer though